# Error on ActionListener method

Tags: java, swing, methods, jframe, jdialog

im coding a Movie Theatre Ticket program,in this program depending on which movie you choose to watch,it will change the displaying poster to the poster according to your choice,however when i execute and choose a certain movie,the program gives out an error pointing towards lblPosterLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:\Users\Roberto\workspace\ProjetoFinaldeCurso\moviePosters\madmax.jpg")));, i have no idea how to fix this,here is the code(btw im writing it in the MVC pattern,because my programming teacher wants it this way)

```
 package view;
public class NewTicketWindow extends JDialog 

/*public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        NewTicketWindow dialog = new NewTicketWindow();
        dialog.setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        dialog.setVisible(true);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}*/


/**
 * Create the dialog.
 */
public NewTicketWindow(Database database)
{
    setDefaultCloseOperation(JDialog.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    this.database = database;
    this.mc = mc;
    setBounds(100, 100, 609, 571);
    getContentPane().setLayout(null);
    contentPanel.setBounds(0, 0, 593, 533);
    contentPanel.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
    getContentPane().add(contentPanel);
    contentPanel.setLayout(null);

    JLabel lblEnterYourName = new JLabel("Enter your Name:");
    lblEnterYourName.setBounds(10, 11, 106, 14);
    contentPanel.add(lblEnterYourName);

    JLabel lblEnterYourCpf = new JLabel("Enter your CPF:");
    lblEnterYourCpf.setBounds(10, 39, 106, 14);
    contentPanel.add(lblEnterYourCpf);

    JLabel lblSelectAMovie = new JLabel("Select a Movie");
    lblSelectAMovie.setBounds(10, 64, 106, 14);
    contentPanel.add(lblSelectAMovie);

    textField = new JTextField();
    textField.setBounds(116, 8, 86, 20);
    contentPanel.add(textField);
    textField.setColumns(10);

    textField_1 = new JTextField();
    textField_1.setBounds(116, 36, 86, 20);
    contentPanel.add(textField_1);
    textField_1.setColumns(10);

    this.moviesComboBox = new JComboBox();
    moviesComboBox.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener()
    {
        public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
        {
            moviesComboBoxEvent(evt);
        }
    });
    this.moviesComboBox.setBounds(116, 61, 204, 20);
    populateMoviesComboBox();
    contentPanel.add(this.moviesComboBox);


    JLabel lblDateShowtime = new JLabel("Date & Showtime");
    lblDateShowtime.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblDateShowtime.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    lblDateShowtime.setBounds(10, 89, 113, 14);
    contentPanel.add(lblDateShowtime);

    JSeparator separator = new JSeparator();
    separator.setBounds(126, 101, 130, 2);
    contentPanel.add(separator);

    JLabel lblShowdate = new JLabel("Showdate :");
    lblShowdate.setBounds(10, 114, 71, 14);
    contentPanel.add(lblShowdate);

    JLabel lblShowtime = new JLabel("Showtime :");
    lblShowtime.setBounds(10, 139, 71, 14);

    contentPanel.add(lblShowtime);

    this.showdateComboBox = new JComboBox();
    showdateComboBox.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.BOLD, 9));
    this.showdateComboBox.setBounds(116, 114, 100, 20);
    populateShowdateComboBox();
    contentPanel.add(this.showdateComboBox);

    this.showtimeComboBox = new JComboBox();
    this.showtimeComboBox.setBounds(116, 139, 100, 20);
    populateShowtimeComboBox();
    contentPanel.add(this.showtimeComboBox);

    JLabel label = new JLabel("");
    label.setBounds(0, 164, 46, 14);
    contentPanel.add(label);

    JLabel lblNumberOfTickets = new JLabel("Number of Tickets");
    lblNumberOfTickets.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    lblNumberOfTickets.setFont(new Font("Tahoma", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    lblNumberOfTickets.setBounds(10, 169, 123, 20);
    contentPanel.add(lblNumberOfTickets);

    JLabel lblAdults = new JLabel("Adults :");
    lblAdults.setBounds(10, 200, 46, 14);
    contentPanel.add(lblAdults);

    this.adultsComboBox = new JComboBox();
    this.adultsComboBox.setBounds(53, 197, 46, 20);
    populateAdultsComboBox();
    contentPanel.add(this.adultsComboBox);

    JLabel lblKids = new JLabel("Kids :");
    lblKids.setBounds(10, 225, 46, 14);
    contentPanel.add(lblKids);

    this.kidsComboBox = new JComboBox();
    this.kidsComboBox.setBounds(53, 224, 46, 20);
    populateKidsComboBox();
    contentPanel.add(this.kidsComboBox);

    lblPosterLabel = new JLabel("New label");
    lblPosterLabel.setIcon(new ImageIcon("C:\\Users\\Roberto\\workspace\\ProjetoFinaldeCurso\\moviePosters\\equilibrium.jpg"));
    lblPosterLabel.setBounds(391, 11, 192, 283);
    contentPanel.add(lblPosterLabel);

    {
        JPanel buttonPane = new JPanel();
        buttonPane.setBounds(159, 500, 434, 33);
        contentPanel.add(buttonPane);
        buttonPane.setLayout(null);
        {
            JButton okButton = new JButton("OK");
            okButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
                {

                }
            });
            okButton.setBounds(273, 5, 65, 23);
            okButton.setActionCommand("OK");
            buttonPane.add(okButton);
            getRootPane().setDefaultButton(okButton);
        }
        {
            JButton cancelButton = new JButton("Cancel");
            cancelButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() 
            {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) 
                {
                    dispose();
                }
            });
            cancelButton.setBounds(345, 5, 84, 23);
            cancelButton.setActionCommand("Cancel");
            buttonPane.add(cancelButton);
        }
    }
    setVisible(true);
}

public void populateMoviesComboBox() 
 {

    this.moviesComboBox.removeAllItems();
    this.moviesComboBox.addItem("");
    for (int i = 0; i < database.getMovie().size(); i++) 
    {
        this.moviesComboBox.addItem(database.getMovie().get(i).getMovieTitle());
    }
}

public void populateShowtimeComboBox()
{
    this.showtimeComboBox.removeAllItems();
    this.showtimeComboBox.addItem("");
    for(int i = 0; i < database.getShowtime().size(); i++)
    {
        this.showtimeComboBox.addItem(database.getShowtime().get(i).getShowtime());
    }
}

public void populateShowdateComboBox()
{
    this.showdateComboBox.removeAllItems();
    this.showdateComboBox.addItem("");
    for(int i = 0; i < database.getShowdate().size(); i++)
    {
        this.showdateComboBox.addItem(database.getShowdate().get(i).getShowdate());
    }
}

public void populateAdultsComboBox()
{
    this.adultsComboBox.removeAllItems();
    this.adultsComboBox.addItem("");
    for(int i = 0; i < database.getAdultsKids().size(); i++)
    {
        this.adultsComboBox.addItem(database.getAdultsKids().get(i).getNumberOfAdultsAndKids());
    }
}

public void populateKidsComboBox()
{
    this.kidsComboBox.removeAllItems();
    this.kidsComboBox.addItem("");
    for(int i = 0; i < database.getAdultsKids().size(); i++)
    {
        this.kidsComboBox.addItem(database.getAdultsKids().get(i).getNumberOfAdultsAndKids());
    }
}

private void cancelPressed()
{
    System.exit(DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
}

public void moviesComboBoxEvent(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) 
{

    if((String)moviesComboBox.getSelectedItem() == "Equilibrium")
    {
        lblPosterLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\Roberto\\workspace\\ProjetoFinaldeCurso\\moviePosters\\equilibrium.jpg")));
    }
    else if((String)moviesComboBox.getSelectedItem() == "Mad Max: Fury Road")
    {
        lblPosterLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\Roberto\\workspace\\ProjetoFinaldeCurso\\moviePosters\\madmax.jpg")));
    }
    else if((String)moviesComboBox.getSelectedItem() == "Rosemary's Baby")
    {
        lblPosterLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\Roberto\\workspace\\ProjetoFinaldeCurso\\moviePosters\\rosemary.jpg")));
    }
    else if((String)moviesComboBox.getSelectedItem() == "Alien")
    {
        lblPosterLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\Roberto\\workspace\\ProjetoFinaldeCurso\\moviePosters\\alien.jpg")));
    }
    else if((String)moviesComboBox.getSelectedItem() == "The Matrix")
    {
        lblPosterLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\Roberto\\workspace\\ProjetoFinaldeCurso\\moviePosters\\matrix.jpg")));
    }
    else if((String)moviesComboBox.getSelectedItem() == "Furious 7")
    {
        lblPosterLabel.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("C:\\Users\\Roberto\\workspace\\ProjetoFinaldeCurso\\moviePosters\\furious.jpg")));
    }
}

 private void moviesComboBoxItemStateChanged(java.awt.event.ItemEvent e) 
 {   
 }
```

}

Comment: What is the actual error?

Comment: What is the error and where is it happening?
 Remember to use "equals" to compare strings instead of ==. Also, since you are providing the full path to the images, i don't think you need to do the "getClass().getResource()".

Comment: Avoid using `null` layouts, pixel perfect layouts are an illusion within modern ui design.  There are too many factors which affect the individual size of components, none of which you can control. Swing was designed to work with layout managers at the core, discarding these will lead to no end of issues and problems that you will spend more and more time trying to rectify